# Why Linkin Park lost their fans in the mid?

Tags: rock

I saw a lot of like pages in Facebook like "Linkin Park ex-fans", "Bring back the old LP", whatever. I love their songs, almost every one *<3* .

So any soldier here who can answer me?

Why people disliked them? (after *Hybrid Theory* I guess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over time most bands innovate, mature, or perhaps reinvent themselves (or whatever you want to call it ...). This goes for their music as well as their style/image.

If they didn't they would probably fade away or be critized for their lack of creativity. In the proces of change you'll always have people that disagree/dislike the way things are heading and would rather have everything stay the way it is.

On the other hand, change enables a band to appeal to a broader audience and might help the band members explore their musical potential to the fullest.

So, my guess is that the Linkin Park fans simply were unhappy with the road taken by the band and wished for the old Linkin Park back.

(Not exactly relevant, but in my opinion Linkin Park made their biggest shift with *Minutes to Midnight* were they sort of left the nu-metal genre and Mike Shinoda wasn't as prominent, due to him being more envolved in producing. So I don't really understand why people would suddenly dislike the band after *Hybrid Theory* specifically, as you claim. But then again, there's no accounting for taste, as they say. )

Comment: @Abhijit I couldn't give you a proper answer as to what genre they 'fit in' after the shift with _Minutes to Midnight_, as the songs are to diverse in my opinion.